# How to fix Manifest error?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have got this error:

> INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

I read that most popular problem is package name,
but my package looks good(all letters small).
so can anyone tell why this happens?
Here is my manifest code. will be glad any help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ua.andriyantonov.donorua" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/DonorUaTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RecipientsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RecipientDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipient_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.RecipientsActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.RecipientsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.RecipientsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.RecipientsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CentersOnMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_centers_on_map"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.RecipientsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.RecipientsActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NeedToKnowActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_need_to_know"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.NeedToKnowDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_need_to_know_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.NeedToKnowActivity"
            android:theme="@style/DonorUaTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.NeedToKnowActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.UserInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/drawer_item_user_info"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" >
        </activity>
        ==================================
        <provider
            android:name=".data.DonorProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/content_authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true" />

        <service android:name=".sync.DonorAuthenticatornService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".sync.DonorSyncService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove `==================================`

Comment: @Sebastian, nope... this didn't solve my problem

Comment: did also rebuild your project after removing the line?

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama, ofcourse, but i still got this error

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ua.andriyantonov.donorua"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"> <-- provide versionCode, versionName

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/> <-- provide min sdk version
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

....

</manifest>
```

Comment: versionCode and min sdk version are overwriten in build.gradle, so thay no needed here.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

android:versionCode and android:versionName are missing

it should be something like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ua.andriyantonov.donorua"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: Version code and version name can be filled in by build.gradle, I don't think they're mandatory anymore.

Comment: Looks like it is realted to 'authorities' attribute. 'authorities' attribute cannot be a resource reference.